# Returning Multiple Values From Map

Tags: ruby, arrays, dictionary, each, enumerator

Is there a way to do:

```
a = b.map{ |e| #return multiple elements to be added to a }
```

Where rather than returning a single object for each iteration to be added to `a`, multiple objects can be returned.

I'm currently achieving this with:

```
a = []
b.map{ |e| a.concat([x,y,z]) }
```

**Is there a way to this in a single line without having to declare `a = []` up front?**

Comment: Can you give an example input and output to let us know,what you are expecting. It helps us to help you ...

Comment: You would never use map() in your code there because each() would suffice. Your code unnecessarily creates an array that you then throw away.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable#flat_map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map)

```
b = [0, 3, 6]
a = b.flat_map { |x| [x, x+1, x+2] }
a # => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use Enumerable#flat_map

Which is probably not much different than:

```
p [1, 2, 3].map{|num| [1, 2, 3]}.flatten 

--output:-
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I believe `flat_map` is more efficient (because you don't need to iterate over the whole array twice)

Comment: It is not the same thing if your map return arrays like `[1, 2, [1, 2, 3]]`